# Typescript lambda error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm watching a typescript tutorial and at one point i have to write this line of code

```
var squareItSimpler = function(h:number, w:number) => h * w;
```

But i just can't get it to work. I keep getting the error

```
The command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe"  --module AMD --target ES3....exited with code 1
```

And i just don't know what to do, am i doing something wrong here ?

The funny this is that the fallowing works:

```
var squareItSimplest = (h:number, w:number) => h * w;
```

I'm using TypeScript 0.9.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do lambdas like that in Typescript, you leave off the `function` keyword. Perhaps your tutorial has an error.

*edit* — from [the spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf):

> TypeScript
>   supports
>   arrow function expressions, a
>   new feature
>   planned
>   for ECMAScript 6. Arrow
>   function expressions are a compact form of function expressions that omit the
>   function
>   keyword and
>   have lexical scoping of
>   this.

Comment: I'm not really sure i keep seeing the guy compile an it works (it's a video tutorial). I know it's might be a bit old but was that code ever valid ? Maybe in previous versions of typescript ? And if so why did they remove it ?

Comment: @toby I'm not a Typescript expert so I could be wrong, but every lambda example I've seen lacks the `function` keyword. You may be correct that it's a recent change.

Comment: @toby updated with a link to what I think is the current language spec

Comment: Not having the ```function``` keyword in a lambda expression was always part of the spec, but the compiler hasn't always been so strict.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

`var squareItSimpler = (h:number, w:number) => h * w;`

or

`var squareItSimpler = function(h:number, w:number) { return h * w; };`